# The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations

Tags: deep-learning

While running my code, I got this error. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is **not an error** but **only a warning**.  This means that your code will still run.  If you wish to get rid of this warning tensorflow suggests you build it from source, which is only available for ubuntu or mac os.  Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) for details on how to build tensorflow from source. Hope this helped.